# Django / FactoryBoy - Equal queries not equal?

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I am writing tests for a Django application and one of my tests is failing with a strange bug where a `assertEqual` comparison is failing, even though the objects in both querysets match.

The test is quite big, so I've written a small test to recreate the error:

```
class StrangeBehaviorTest(TestCase):

    def test_init(self):
        purchase = ArrangementPurchaseFactory()

        self.assertTrue(purchase)
        self.assertTrue(purchase.arrangement_period)
        self.assertEqual(ArrangementPurchase.objects.count(), 1)

        fetched = ArrangementPurchase.objects.filter(
            id=1)

        self.assertEqual(fetched.first().id, purchase.id)
        self.assertEqual(fetched.first(), purchase)

        self.assertEqual(fetched, ArrangementPurchase.objects.filter(
            id=1
        ))
```

When I run this test the very last assert fails with the following error:

```
AssertionError: <QuerySet [<ArrangementPurchase: 1 : user_0 - Profound bandwidth-monitored pricing structure (vanaf 2019-04-24)>]> != <QuerySet [<ArrangementPurchase: 1 : user_0 - Profound bandwidth-monitored pricing structure (vanaf 2019-04-24)>]>
```

I've verified that my `ArrangementPurchaseFactory` is subclassing the `DjangoModelFactory` (as can be seen below)

```
class ArrangementPurchaseFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = arrangement_models.ArrangementPurchase

    user = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory)
    arrangement_period = factory.SubFactory(ArrangementPeriodFactory)
    purchase_date = factory.LazyFunction(
        lambda: timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=10)
    )
    expire_date = factory.LazyFunction(
        lambda: timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
    )
    tenant_demo_purchase = False
    price_paid = factory.LazyFunction(lambda: Decimal(0))
    linked_order_id = factory.Faker('sha1')
    rabo_purchase_pending = False
```

As far as I can tell the object in both querysets exists in the database (the object has an id value), and the pk value of the `fetched` query matches the existing `purchase.id`

So why is the test failing? Does anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because though the values of these querySets are equal, they are actually different objects.

What you need is `assertQuerysetEqual`. From the docs:

> **TransactionTestCase.assertQuerysetEqual**(qs, values, transform=repr,
>   ordered=True, msg=None)[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/] Asserts that a queryset qs returns a
>   particular list of values values.
>
> The comparison of the contents of qs and values is performed using the
>   function transform; by default, this means that the repr() of each
>   value is compared. Any other callable can be used if repr() doesn’t
>   provide a unique or helpful comparison.
>
> By default, the comparison is also ordering dependent. If qs doesn’t
>   provide an implicit ordering, you can set the ordered parameter to
>   False, which turns the comparison into a collections.Counter
>   comparison. If the order is undefined (if the given qs isn’t ordered
>   and the comparison is against more than one ordered values), a
>   ValueError is raised.
>
> Output in case of error can be customized with the msg argument.

Answer (score 1):

Django doesn't provide any specific equality comparison between `QuerySet` instances (see the code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L185).

When no custom `__eq__` method is provided, Python falls back to comparing object addresses in memory.
Two different instances of a `QuerySet`, even if built from the same parameters, will have different addresses, and compare unequal.

If you want to compare the *contents* of the querysets (i.e the list of objects in the database), you'll have to evaluate them, for instance casting them to lists:

```
self.assertEqual(list(fetched), list(ArrangementPurchase.objects.filter(id=1)))
```

With this, Python will compare the lists, whose `__eq__` method compares the *contents* of the lists instead of their memory addresses.

NB: If the lists have more than 1 item, you'll have to take ordering into account.

Another option would be to use `assertQuerysetEqual`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertQuerysetEqual

Comment: Thank you Xelnor! This is really useful to know and just helped me!